# Python Pandas - Lookup from a Dataframe to an Excel Document

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am new to Python to if this is easy then apologies. I have created a dataframe using pandas which is sales data summed up by which store the products are sold in, taken from our internal database. I need to somehow get this data from pandas to lookup on the same store code in the excel sheet and paste it into the correspoding column in the excel database. So an example below:

My pd database looks similar like this:

| Store number | Week 14 | Week 15 | Week 16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 222 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 2344 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2231 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

My Excel database looks like this

| store number | Week 14 | Week 15 | Week 16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2344 | 1 |  |  |
| 222 | 3 |  |  |
| 123 | 4 |  |  |
| 2231 | 3 |  |  |

So essentailly i would need to do an lookup on the dataframe to the excel sheet for weeks 15 and 16. The reason i need to get the data to the excel sheet is becuase it is the backdata of another larger report.

I cant really provide the sheets as the data is confidential but any advice would be greatly received.

Comment: Can you not just overwrite the excel sheet with the completed dataframe?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say `sheet` do you mean it as it is on Excel or as per your example where it’s just a column?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Warcupine. No cannot overwrite as there is other data in there such as store names etc

Comment: Danail, I mean as a whole sheet. so the Excel sheet is called 'All QTY Sales' for clarity

Comment: you can load your excel sheet into a dataframe then merge it with the dataframe from the internal database and then overwrite the excel sheet with the merged dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

When you load your excel file into pandas using `read_excel`, you can use [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update only the empty values in the excel sheet from the other dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [ { "Store number": 123, "Week 14": 4, "Week 15": 2, "Week 16": 4 }, { "Store number": 222, "Week 14": 3, "Week 15": 1, "Week 16": 1 }, { "Store number": 2344, "Week 14": 1, "Week 15": 3, "Week 16": 1 }, { "Store number": 2231, "Week 14": 3, "Week 15": 3, "Week 16": 3 } ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_excel = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")
df_excel = df_excel.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True) # replace any empty strings to np.nan, just to be sure

df_excel.set_index('store number',inplace=True) # set the index to store number to ensure the right store numbers are updated
df_excel.update(df.set_index('Store number'), overwrite=False)
df_excel.reset_index(inplace=True)

df_excel.to_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One question, the data in the excel has other columns that I don’t want to overwrite. Can I put a data frame in a range. Ie in the above example the store ref is column A and the weeks are columns F - I?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment. What this does is it temporarily sets `store name` as index and updates all empty cells in `df_excel` with the matching cells in `df`. In this case only week 14, 15 and 16 are updated as they exist in both dataframes. Any other columns that may exist in your excel file are ignored and will persist.

Answer (score 0):

Say your first dataframe is called df. At first you need to set "Store number" as the index as follows:

```
df=df.set_index("Store number", inplace=True)
```

[image]

Next, say the dataframe which you import from excel file is called df_excel as shown:[image]

You need to apply the df.map() function as shown below in order to map the Week 15 and Week 16 values from df into df_excel as shown:
[image]

```
df_excel["Week 15"]=df_excel["store number"].map(df["Week 15"])
df_excel["Week 16"]=df_excel["store number"].map(df["Week 16"])
```